# Error : Cannot be resolved or is not a Field

Tags: android, eclipse, android-launcher

Getting this specific error **:** ***Cannot be resolved or is not a Field***

[image]

[image]

I tried Cleaning the Project and *Debugged* (**`F11`**) and Build the project. But still the same problem persists.

[image]

```html
if(from[i].equals("me")){
    mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble_left, null); //error
}else{
    mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble_right, null); //error
}

chatMessageMicrophone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chatMessageMicrophone); //error
chatMessageSend = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chatMessageSend); //error
```

Similarly, there are 30 more errors like this.

Comment: Better you post the xml and java code here

Comment: Isnt it clear that you are missing libraries..?

Comment: Code Added.
Edited @dEvElOpIt_Sanskar and which library am I missing almas shaikh ?

Comment: Are you getting a red error line below **R** in R.layout.bubble_left for example ?

Comment: not below **R** but below *bubble_left*

Answer (score 2):

May be you have imported the `android.R` file instead of `your_package.R` file. If you have done that then replace the below import statement

```
import android.R;
```

with

```
import your_package.R;
```